# Accessing AngularJS scope variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to access a Angular form variable in my jquery code. 
I have a controller for a html page, and on clicking the button, i am calling a jQuery function. I want to access a form variable in the jQuery method.

I want to access the value of carId , in my jQuery method.

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  name = "myForm" id="form1">
 <select name = "option" 
    id="yourCar" 
        data-ng-model="form.carId"
    data-ng-options="option.id as option.name for options in options.carNames">
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: How about using `ng-click` on your button instead? Preferably, don't use jQuery click listeners if you're working with angular in your app.

Comment: you could wrap the jquery code inside a directive in the link function and can use the form variable in it

Comment: I was finally able to achieve what I wanted. I created a hidden div in the same page <div id= "hide" hidden>{{form.carId}}</div>. then in the jQuery I had the code :  var entityId =$('#hide').scope().form.carId;

Comment: @Cerbrus : my requirement in this case needs a jQuery implementation. Otherwise I would have used what you had suggested.

Comment: _''needs a jQuery implementation."_: May I ask why?

Answer (score 0):

As @Cerbrus pointed out, you shouldn't be using *jQuery* along with *AngularJS*.

However, you can always access the **value** of an `input` with *jQuery* despite the fact it is build with *AngularJS*:

```
$('#yourCar').val();
```

Side note: *AngularJS* has a light version of *jQuery* included which lets you use some useful methods like `angular.forEach();`, `angular.copy();`, ...

Answer (score -1):

1. You have to know this scope belong to which controller, directive?.
2. Put your jQuery code, you want to manipulate, access "carId" variable into these controller, directive.